# How do I uninstall the Cinelerra package?

Tags: uninstall, cinelerra

I am new to ubuntu, I installed **cinelerra** through these steps

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

now i want to **uninstall** it, how is it done?

Answer (score 3):

From the terminal, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge cinelerra\*
```

This will completely remove (uninstall) the package.

Comment: Also, remove the apt repository if you don't want it to download the repository information (package lists and the likes). It'll probably show up in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and start or contain `cinelerra-ppa` in its filename. Once you find that, you may want to remove that file (with `sudo rm [filename]`)

Comment: thanks for the advice but when i tried to remove apt repository, this was what i found now what should i do?sankar@sankar-Inspiron-N5010:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/: Is a directory

Comment: You should `cd` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then do an `ls`, and the PPAs will be listed, then do a `sudo rm [filename_of_cinelerra]`